# Php iframe to amp-youtube

Tags: php, amp-html

I want change iframe to amp-youtube. I did it, but there is a problem. I use youtube video configiration but amp-youtube want only video shortcode. So i am working fix this problem in line 2. But line 2 is not working

```
$this->html = str_replace("//www.youtube.com/embed/","",$this->html);
$this->html = str_replace("?rel=0&showinfo=0","",$this->html); // This is not working
$this->html = preg_replace('/<iframe\s+.*?\s+src=(".*?").*?<\/iframe>/', '<amp-youtube data-videoid=$1 layout="responsive" width="480" height="270"></amp-youtube>', $this->html);
```

Line 2 str_replace not working. How can i do this another way ? Example preg_replace ?

Correct code:

```
<amp-youtube
    data-videoid="mGENRKrdoGY"
    layout="responsive"
    width="480" height="270"></amp-youtube>
```

My code is printing like this. so video in not opening

```
<amp-youtube
        data-videoid="mGENRKrdoGY?rel=0&showinfo=0"
        layout="responsive"
        width="480" height="270"></amp-youtube>
```

there is also another problem. If iframe link is not youtube, i want change iframe to amp-iframe.

Comment: That str_replace line works absolutely fine - provided the input is actually as shown. Guess: Your variable probably contains already (properly) encoded HTML, so that the `&` is actually `&amp;`, so you need to use the latter in your search parameter for str_replace as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve by this :

```
<?php
$iframeCode = '<iframe width="100%" height="450" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/mGENRKrdoGY?rel=0&showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
preg_match('/embed\/([\w+\-+]+)[\"\?]/', $iframeCode,$match); 
echo '<amp-youtube
    data-videoid="'.$match[1].'"
    layout="responsive"
    width="480" height="270"></amp-youtube>';
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

it working but only for the first video.. i have 3 videos in $content but it only get yt id of the first video.. can you please loop it.. to get all videos embed via iframe in $content..

**bellow is the example**

```
$content_description = 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/V6LP8m4GpVc" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0"></iframe>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an <div class="embed-container"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xfLQcsP0L18" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0"></iframe></div>';
```

```
    preg_match('/embed\/([\w+\-+]+)[\"\?]/', $content_description,$match); 
    $yt = '<amp-youtube
    data-videoid="'.$match[1].'"
    layout="responsive"
    width="480" height="270"></amp-youtube>';

    echo $yt;
```

**Result**

```
    <amp-youtube
    data-videoid="V6LP8m4GpVc"
    layout="responsive"
    width="480" height="270"></amp-youtube>
```

i want to echo all the content as well.. i am converting existing php website to amp. to covert iframe to amp-youtube on same exact same spot. and img to amp-img as well.

Comment: what is `$match` in first line, can you explain?